# Responsive iframe (google maps) and weird resizing

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe, responsive-design

I am trying to add a Google Map to my design, that is supposed to be responsive. I've used the same code that works out for images... But for some reason, the map's iframe resizes with dimensions I didn't pick.

HTML

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?vpsrc=6&amp;ctz=-480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=210840796990572645528.00049770919ccd6759de3&amp;t=m&amp;ll=30.751278,68.203125&amp;spn=84.446143,175.429688&amp;z=2&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="635" height="300">    </iframe>​
```

and the CSS

```
iframe {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto; /*IE8 bug fix*/
vertical-align: middle;}
```

Or you can view it live and fiddle with it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/corinne/pKUzU/
​(if you cut away the CSS, you will see what i mean).

My question is how to make this iframe/map be responsive without losing its wanted height?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This solution is from Dave Rupert / Chris Coyier (I think). It requires a wrapper div but works pretty well.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="iframe-rwd">
        <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Seattle,+WA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=seattle&amp;sll=37.822293,-85.76824&amp;sspn=6.628688,16.907959&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Seattle,+King,+Washington&amp;z=11&amp;ll=47.60621,-122.332071&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Seattle,+WA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=seattle&amp;sll=37.822293,-85.76824&amp;sspn=6.628688,16.907959&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Seattle,+King,+Washington&amp;z=11&amp;ll=47.60621,-122.332071" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.iframe-rwd  {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.iframe-rwd iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The code above will fill up it's container and hold it's original aspect ratio. This is nice for responsive grids. You can just pop this into whatever grid block you like and it will size itself automatically, even when things are resized.

Comment: thank you very much, it works, miracle! :) Wish I could give you some points, but unfortunately am still a newbie here!

Comment: @cpg Do you have a reference for this code? Trying to understand it better. Specifically, it seems to work without the need for overflow:hidden, possibly due to the 100% sizing of the iframe?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php   Looks like the padding-bottom above may be a little suspect. Still seems to work but a little more reading is probably in order.

Comment: Also of interest: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Comment: don't know how it works but works perfectly.. thank you so much.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!