# Google Chart API breaking out of container on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design, google-visualization

I'm developing a mobile site using Google's chart API.  Everything is working beautifully and scaling like it should on other tested devices, but for some reason, Google's "table" chart is breaking out of its container when viewed on the iPhone.  It looks fine on a shrunk browser window, an Android tablet, and on a Galaxy SII.  I have confirmed that it is not an issue with mobile Safari.

Chart is loaded via an iFrame and is scaled to fit width: 100% of its container, which is Dreamweaver "Fluid Grid Layout -- Gridcontainer" element.  Both a column chart and a line chart both scale properly to 100%, but the table grows to fit all content and then breaks out of the gridcontainer.

On other devices, the grid displays what it can within the boundaries and adds scrolling.

This is the php/html code that draws the chart to the page.

```
<div id="top-prods" class="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
<?php
    if($charts->isData() == "true"){
        echo "<iframe id=\"top-chart\" src=\"controls/charts/top_prods.php?loc=".$loc."&comp=".$company_id;
        if($xDate != "") {echo "&xDate=".$xDate;} 
        if($yDate != "") {echo "&yDate=".$xDate;}
        echo "\" style=\"width:100%;\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>";
    }
?>
```

The only css is defined on the Gridcontainer, since the iFrame SHOULD just resize to fit within the container.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having a similar problem as this: [Responsive iframe (google maps) and weird resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676725/responsive-iframe-google-maps-and-weird-resizing)

The CSS in the first Answer looks like it could be easily ported over.