# Google maps embed relative size

Tags: css

I have embedded a google map successfully with this [Responsive iframe (google maps) and weird resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676725/responsive-iframe-google-maps-and-weird-resizing)

But I cannot change the width, it's too wide. Changing width:100% works but then it's not in the middle of page anymore.

Comment: Your question does not show that you research enough. I recommend a better research after you came here to question. You also did not explain and show us an example of your problem.

Comment: The code is in the link in cpg's answer. I ask what parameter to change to modify the width, but keeping map centered. "padding-bottom" changes height correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Use :**

```
<div style = "text-align:center;">
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?vpsrc=6&amp;ctz=-480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=210840796990572645528.00049770919ccd6759de3&amp;t=m&amp;ll=30.751278,68.203125&amp;spn=84.446143,175.429688&amp;z=2&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="635" height="300">    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't help unfortunately